# httpclient postasync windows phone 8.1 universal app second call 404 error

Tags: http, post, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, universal

I have a problem with httpclient in a universal windows phone 8.1 app. 
I've been looking but i have not a valid solution in any post.

the problem is that, when i call to the web service first time runs correctly, but when i call it, second or third time, gives me an error 404.

Until you restart the application will not run again.

i need to send that data in a post function cause i want to send a xml formated to string.

my code is very simple:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new
                NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain")
        };


        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("XMLText", XMLText),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", "textParam1")
                    });

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = await client.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog(responseString);
            await msgbox.ShowAsync();
        }
```

and my web service is even simpler:

```
[WebMethod]
    public String SetEnvioXML(string XMLText, string param1)
    {
        return XMLText;
    }
```

Any solution?

Sorry for my english and thaks for all!

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Fiddler traces would help.

Comment: Hi everybody and thank for your help. i continue whit the problem, but i have a new factor. I tried to remove the windows authentication of my web service (IIS), and it rules ok.

is it possible that httpclient, lost the credentials?

its weird, cause first call runs ok, and the second call follows the same path...

any idea??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, i changed the autentication from windows autentication, to basic autentication in IIS, setting the domain in it. Then i try that:

client = new HttpClient();
                var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "usuario", "contraseña"))));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;

And it rules. Thanks for all of your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code may be this will works, 
First try to run this on Google Rest Client or Post Man

```
            HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();
            httpRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            httpRequest.RequestUri = URL;
            httpRequest.Content = formContent ;

            response  =await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but i probe it and recieve the same error. I dont know what happend.

Comment: what's that exception you got

Comment: In the second call, "response" recives the next: {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Length: 0
}}

Comment: Yes. I check in rest client. If I probe in google chrome, i can acces unlimited times. Thank you very much for your help