# WindowsPhone HttpWebRequest to ashx WebService

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ashx

I have a problem with HttpWebRequest:

I have an ashx code in a visual studio ws that simply does:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var a = context.Request.Form["a"];
        var b = context.Request.Form["b"];
        context.Response.Write(a + " " + b);
    }
```

I tried to call it with advancedRestClient and it worked, but if i call it with my windows phone device I get a not found exception and the request doesn't reach any breakpoint.
this is my WP code:

```
    public void PostIt2()
    {

        string url = "http://localhost/blablacode/ecc.ashx";
        // Create a new HttpWebRequest object.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
        request.Method = "POST";

        // start the asynchronous operation
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

        // Keep the main thread from continuing while the asynchronous
        // operation completes. A real world application
        // could do something useful such as updating its user interface. 
        allDone.WaitOne();
    }

    private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        string postData = "{'a': 'avar','b':'bvar'}";

        // Convert the string into a byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Write to the request stream.
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        // Close the stream object
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
        allDone.Set();
    }
```

I took the code from MSDN so i don't know what i'm doing wrong, i also tried a lot of methods found on the internet, the only thing important for me is that i have to use `HttpWebRequest` and not `HttpClient`.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, really thanks god is friday.
i was using as url "localhost/eccecc.ashx"

device's localhost is not same localhost of computer.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the problem is not in the code.
Are your services accesible from the phone??
Are your proyect configure with internet access??

If all its ok, look at this post:
[httpclient postasync windows phone 8.1 universal app second call 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934803/httpclient-postasync-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app-second-call-404-error)

Comment: Honestly i don't know, this ashx file is a new file added to an already existing WS made with asmx which is used by hundered of phones, i have to configure it differently to be invoked by httpwebresponse?